# How does MS SQL Server Management Studio connect to the server?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

Does anyone know exactly what method SMS uses to connect to servers?

We're suddenly having a problem with a customer machine that can no longer connect to their server. It appears to be TLS related, perhaps due to the March update?

SMS is working fine. The simple solution would be to use their connection method in our connection string, assuming that is possible.

Comment: Check the event log, get the error messages, check network traffic, etc. Good luck.

Comment: We have that, but it's not terribly useful. SSL error somewhere, which implies TLS changes, but good luck finding that.